# Exclude All Posts Which Do Not Have A Tag Assigned

Tags: wp-query, query-posts

Basically I have regular Category Listings that include posts WITH tags and posts WITHOUT tags.

I need to modify the loop so that it ONLY includes posts which have one or more tags assigned to them.

Is there a way do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

here is an example loop..
you can change the number of tag to exclude based on the amount you want...

```
<?php 
if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();

// GET THE TAGS OF CURRENT POST IN LOOP AND COUNT THE AMOUNT
    $posttags = get_the_tags();
    $howmany = count($posttags);
    if($howmany > 2) {
?>
    <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>

<?php
    } else {
    // do nothing
    }
    endwhile; 
?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

.

Hope This Helps
Sagive

Comment: The Tag ID will not be known.
I only want the loop to display posts which HAVE a tag set.  There's over 100 tags.  The posts WITH tags usually have 3 - 5.  I only want them to appear in category listings.

Comment: i see.. sorry - missread you question.. fixed the solution.

Comment: Thanks.  That does exactly what I want.
The only problem is that it now doesn't show the right posts per page.

For example:

I have 10 posts per page, and there's 120 posts (with tags).  Instead of showing just 12 paged pages with 10 posts each, it shows about 25 paged pages with varying amounts of posts per page - between 2 and 8.

Comment: paste your current loop so i wont mass it up and i would gladly help

Comment: Currrent loop looks like this:

`<?php $posts = query_posts( $query_string . '&orderby=title&order=asc&post_type=glossary' ); ?>

<?php
     
if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();

// GET THE TAGS OF CURRENT POST IN LOOP AND COUNT THE AMOUNT
    $posttags = get_the_tags();
    $howmany = count($posttags);
    if($howmany > 2) {
 
?>





<div class="cat-posts">


<h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>


        <?php
   the_excerpt();
        ?>

 

</div> 


<?php
    } else {
    // 
    }
endwhile;
?>

<?php endif; ?>`

Comment: i meant paste in your question :( - how can i read it now... never mind - i see you are calling a custom post type (glossary).. for that i need the name of the tag taxonomy...  that is why it doesent work..

Comment: It uses the built-in tags.
That loop above is also used on regular posts types.